# How many number of wsdl can we uploaded in Wsp service of wdp?

Tags: ibm-datapower

I have tried uploading multiple WSDL files in web service proxy. Can anyone tell me what is the maximum limit of WSDL files can be uploaded in a single service of WSP?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Aditya! Your question needs improvement, please read about how to ask good questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

There is no "hard" limit. As many as you need but consider that you will have to maintain all the WSDL's and XSD's also so it might get "messy" having a lot in the same WSP.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for not having too much WSDLs per single WSP is that when touching anything in the WSP and then clicking Apply, all WSDLs will be recompiled, which depending of the number and sizes of imported XSDs can take quite some time.